# Trying to import data to SQL using Python

Tags: python, sql

I'm pulling data into Python from my SQL server, but am having issues loading the data back into SQL from Python. My Windows password only has read access, however, we use CyberArc where I can get a username/password that has read/write privileges. When I sign into SSMS as a different user using the CyberArc username/pass, I can write to the DB, but when I use Python, I get this error:
File "Project3.py", line 84, in 
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cars (brand) values('testing')")
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'cars', database 'LETS', schema 'dbo'. (229) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I've tried using the pyodbc connect after running SSMS as a dif user, and have tried:
runas /user:Domain\Username "python Project3.py"

Here's the script:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
from pandas import DataFrame
cars = {'brand': ['Honda Civic']#,'Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
#'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
    }
df = DataFrame(cars, columns= ['brand'])#, 'Price'])
print (df)
cursor = conn.cursor()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cars (brand) values('testing')")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What parameters are you passing into your pyodbc connection string?  If you are using `Trusted_Connection=yes` that could be overriding any username/password you specify and use your windows account

Comment: HI - thanks for the response. The connection is: conn=pyodbc.connect('driver={sql server} 'server=Myserver;' 'database=MyDataBase;' 'userName=MyUserName' 'password=MyDomain\User' 'trustedConnection=no;'